# Phd in Computer Science Enrollment after M.tech in Electronics and Communications

Tags: phd, research-process, computer-science, career-path

I'm looking for some experience who completed or pursuing  PhD  Computer Science Enrollment and experience after M.tech in  Electronics and Communications.

**Myself:** I completed M.Tech in ECE (digital signal processing with work published springer paper) in 2014 and 7.5 years of IT fulltime experience (including 3 years engineering research and software development including AI development, cloud engineering, DevOps and python development). I have couple of IT certifications and 1 year professional course work of software development engineering (data structures, LLD, HLD) at scale.  [Linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/in/jatinder-singh-030073132/)

**Situations:**

**Research work predefined**: I have gotten clearance form research head/management of my employer about my next research assignment can be published to university as PhD research topic/problem.

**University enrollment and guide**: My task to manage enrollment in the university and guide who can supervise and recognize my work.

**Query:** whether it is possible to enroll in Phd in Computer Science after M.tech in Electronics and Communications

Please suggest me best way  or some experience to move ahead to pick university and enrolment process.

I heard from someone that  Master degree must in  in CS to enroll in PhD CS

Comment: For your last sentence, it depends on where you want to study. For the rest it depends on whether you have quite a lot of undergrad cs courses behind you. But, in the US, things are a bit more permissive.

Comment: You will probably want to mention the country in which you wish to pursue a PhD degree. It seems like you are asking for an industry sponsored university; many universities are quite keen to have industry sponsored research.  As an aside, the main challenge, however, is that many companies want engineering outputs, as opposed to research outputs.  For example, many companies want outputs equivalent to an undergraduate project as opposed to papers.

Comment: you are right  @VitaminE, I'm currently working on assignments which PostDoc students completed basic feasibility, improving/building industry use cases into products. Mostly I'm looking fully funded PhD in USA.